# Open new window for multiple edit records

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

What I have here is a table that displays record from my database. It also generates dynamic *checkboxes* along with the fetched record. What I need to do is to open a *new window* using `window.open`, instead for the page to go to **editor.php**. Any help will be gladly appreciated.

**MySQLi Query**

```
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"'.($row['pr'] == ""?"disabled ":"").' style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkbox"></td>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
function setCheckboxes3(act) {
    $('.checkbox').not(':disabled').prop('checked', act == 1 ? true : false);
    //or $('.checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', act == 1 ? true : false)
}
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            if (!confirm('Edit this Record(s)?')) {
                return
            }
        } else {
            if (!confirm('WARNING !!! All Purchase Order that included in this Record(s) will be deleted.')) {
                return
            }
        }

        var frm = document.myform;
        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            frm.action = 'editpr.php';
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure want to continue?')) {
                return
            }
        }
        frm.submit();
    })
})
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="button edit" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Edit</b></span></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried using target="_blank" tag on your <a>?

Comment: @LoganWayne yes, But I want new window open like in the modal box

Comment: You can also use target="_blank" on your <form>

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/modal-box

Comment: @LoganWayne not yet, if it possible to pass the element inside of modalbox?